# Text and images overlapping on decreasing size of window

Tags: html, css

I have a container div (width:100%) containing 3 more divs arranged along the container (of widths 33.3% each).

On decreasing the width of the window, all the images start to overlap. The text as well. How can I stop this?

I see that stack overflow has a mechanism which prevents the user to decrease width beyond a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the css class `min-width`.
Eg:

```
.myclass {
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

need to set `100%` width to the image

```
img.class-name {
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Jishnu, I don't know if he needs width: 100%, because maybe width of the image will be less then container width, and I don't know if he needs it to have containers width..